# Can you tell or recommend about the books which is based on Shilpa Shastra?

Tags: scripture, book-recommendation, idols, art, shilpa-shastras

Can anyone provide me with the information of some books which deals with Shilpa Shastra i.e rules and regulations for making a Moorti or Vigraha of a certain Devi/Deva?

Comment: Read Agni Purana, Vishnudharmottara Purana, Hayashirsha Pancaratra, Sanatkumara samhita, Jayakhya samhita, Padma samhita.